# How do I remove cssLint highlight in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, highlight, csslint

I'm (trying to) using CSS Lint plugin for Sublime Text 2.

Once I've run it, I can't remove the highlight.
"Escape" just remove the console window.
Hitting again the command just "re-lints".

[image]

How can I remove the highlight?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Changing the Preferences for a ST2 Plugin

1. Go to `Preferences -> Package Settings -> CSS Lint`
2. Choose `Settings - Default` to see the default settings for this
   plugin.
3. If there are items in this section you would like to change, copy and paste the default settings in the `Settings - User` file, and then change them there.

This process will ensure that your changed settings are preserved if/when the plugin is updated.

---

### Another Plugin Option

As a side note, I prefer using [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter). It includes cssLint and has a pretty robust set of settings options. You can find more information about this plugin on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761592/error-with-sublimelinter-in-sublimetext-2/13373308#13373308).